# New data clears selection

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

I'm using `@swimlane/ngx-datatable` to display data from the server. I poll these data, so every 1 min. I got a new set of data. My problem is, if the user selects a row in the data table after the polling the data gets rewritten by new data and the selection gets lost. To demonstrate it I created a dummy example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fsyhay?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

[image]

- Wait till data gets displayed in the table
- Select a row
- Wait till new data arrives (4s, setInterval)
- The selection is cleared

Any idea how to solve this?

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, VERSION, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { ColumnMode, SelectionType } from "@swimlane/ngx-datatable";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  SelectionType = SelectionType;
  rows = [];
  columns = [{ prop: "name" }, { name: "Gender" }, { name: "Company" }];
  selected = [];

  onSelect({ selected }) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.rows = [
        { name: "Austin", gender: "Male", company: "Swimlane" },
        { name: "Dany", gender: "Male", company: "KFC" },
        { name: "Molly", gender: "Female", company: "Burger King" }
      ];
    }, 4000);
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div>
    <ngx-datatable class="material" [rows]="rows" [columns]="columns" [selected]="selected"
        [selectionType]="SelectionType.single" (select)="onSelect($event)">
    </ngx-datatable>
</div>
```